# ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it, ORA-06512:, ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Question: Create a single trigger named trg_job_date that will update the JOB_LAST_UPDATE column in the job table to the current date on insert or update.   Test the trigger with an insert and update statement – include the insert and update statements.

So I'm trying to update `job_last_update` in job through a trigger but I read that I can have the same table I want to update in the trigger. My main problem is that `job_last_update` is only available in the job table.

Here is the erd:
[image]

And here is my code so far:

```
create or replace trigger trg_job_date 
after insert or update
on job
for each row 

begin
    update job
        set job_last_update = current_date;
end;

insert into job (job_code, job_description, job_chg_hour, job_last_update)
values('511', 'Hardware management', '22.11', '4/4/2021');

update job 
set job_description = 'Hardware Manager' 
where job_code = 511;

select * from job; --using this to test whether the trigger worked properly
```

The trigger runs no problem, however when I try to run my insert statement it gives me the error:

```
ORA-04091: table SQL_IUARPVSJLXIJWEVKOWRJRCSXZ.JOB is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "SQL_IUARPVSJLXIJWEVKOWRJRCSXZ.TRG_JOB_DATE", line 2
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

What do I need to do in order to make my code do what I need it to do?

Comment: **Never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Use DATE values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new transaction with a separate update. Use the `:new` pseudo table in a *before* trigger to modify the column as part of the same transaction.

```
create or replace trigger trg_job_date 
before insert or update
on job
for each row 
begin
    :new.job_last_update := sysdate;
end;
```

See documentation, here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4F93F21E-BA7F-4378-87E6-46A8E4C03287

Comment: I keep getting this error when I run your code: 
Errors: TRIGGER TRG_JOB_DATE
Line/Col: 2/26 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ; indicator
The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.
How would I resolve this?

Comment: There was a typo in my example, which I have corrected.

Comment: I see. Thank you!